# Fullcalendar time block transparent

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am developing a webapp and embedded the Fullcalendar in it. I am not sure but is it possible to set each event block's color to be transparent?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#calendar').fullcalendar({ eventColor: 'rgba(150,150,150, 0.5)' });
```

**0.5** stands for alpha

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but FullCalendar uses css styling extensively so I would think you can.

Answer (score 1):

See the [eventColor](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventColor/) property. I think that is what you're looking for.

```
$('#calendar').fullcalendar({ eventColor: 'transparent' });
```

Comment: I also had to specify the text color to be black to see the title text `textColor: 'black'`